# Open file from command line and display what was typed

Tags: c, file-io, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to input only one filename from command line. Then I want to use an If statement to compare the filename to 4 different names I'm expecting to see. If I don't get one of the 4 expected file names then I need to print it back to the user with what was inputted and then exit the program safely.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
....
}
```

I've been trying a lot of different methods of getting this done, but I just can't figure it out. I was thinking maybe the way I take the input argument is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-edit

I just want to be clear I don't want you to be a leech and solve the question I have for me. Just at least point me in the correct direction. I can't figure how to make a for loop work with the filename.

```
for(argv == "UnexpectedFile.csv"){
    printf("this is an unexpected file: %c", argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: the for() statement should look more like: `if( ( strcmp(argv[1], "UnexpectedFile.csv" ) && ,,,, ) then printout the failure message

Comment: You could eventually initialize a string array with your expected filenames and iterate through it with a `for`, and inside it add an `if` statement to determine if the argument is one of those filenames.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`strcmp()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) from `string.h` to compare strings like

```
strcmp(argv[1], "unexpectedfile.csv");
```

It returns `0` when the strings are equal.

If you have the 4 file names in as an array of strings, say `expectedFile`, do

```
for(i=0; i<4 && strcmp(argv[1], expectedFile[i])!=0; ++i);
```

If the value of `i` is the total number of file names (ie, `4`) after this loop, `argv[1]` is an unexpected file.
Otherwise, value of `i` would be the index of the file name string in the `expectedFile` array.

The command line arguments are stored in the 2-dimensional `char` array `argv`.

`argv[0]` would be the name of the executed file. The arguments you give start only from `argv[1]` onwards.

`argc` will have the total number of command line arguments *including* the file name stored in `argc`. So if there are 'no' arguments, `argc` would be `1`.
In your case the file name is the only argument, so `argc` would be `2`.

You must check if `argc` is at least `2` before you access `argv[1]` to prevent the program from accessing `argv[1]` when it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

*(You do not ask for complete code solution (and do not provide enough of your code for that). So here are the pointers in the right direction you want.)*

The comparison you do with a simple `pointer == pointer` does not really compare the content of the strings. That is what e.g. `strcmp ()` is for, as proposed by @user3629249.

And in order to print out what was given as commandline argument, you should use `"%s\n"`.

And in order to set up a for loop, you will have to do the syntax right: `for(init assignment; condition; step operation)`.

*(If you need more help, you will have to provide more details on what behaviour you get and what you do not like about it. Currently your code looks more like compiler errors, which you did not quote, than a problem with the behaviour goal...)*